# What is the `StorePath` for OPCUA Server Application Certificate in Configuration file for Linux Machine?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, opc-ua

Below StorePath is for Windows Machine in OPCUA Server Configuration file. So what should be the `ApplicationCertificate StorePath` for `Linux Machine`.

```
<ApplicationCertificate>
            <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
            <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\pki\own</StorePath>
            <SubjectName>CN=OPCUA Server, C=US, S=Arizona, O=OPC Foundation, DC=localhost</SubjectName>
</ApplicationCertificate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the folder locations of the **CommonApplicationData**

```
ENM: System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
WIN: C:\ProgramData
LIN: /usr/share
OSX: /usr/share
```

For more: [INFO](https://jimrich.sk/environment-specialfolder-on-windows-linux-and-os-x/)

For the folders in OPC foundation there is going to be a folder structure of this: `/usr/share/OPC Foundation/pki/own/certs` for certificates (.der)
and `/usr/share/OPC Foundation/pki/own/private` for private keys (.pfx)

Linux doens't use whitespaces in folders so hold that in mind!

EDIT: You can also use this:

```
%LocalApplicationData%

ENM: System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
WIN: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local
LIN: /home/USER/.local/share
OSX: /Users/USER/.local/share
```

For more info take a look at **[.Net Standard Console applications on Windows, Linux, iOS etc.](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/Docs/Certificates.md#net-core-applications-on-windows-linux-ios-etc)**

***[Extra information!](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux#)***

Edit2: **[click here for better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946892/c-sharp-opc-ua-server-application-has-not-been-created-pki-certificate-in-linu/75947695#75947695)**

Comment: I used <StorePath>/usr/share/OPCFoundation/pki/own</StorePath> path but still `OPCFoundation` folder not created in Linux machine.

Comment: @MdShahnewaz I made an edit to the post, also read the documentation provided by OPC foundation very good. It is hard to understand.

Comment: I tried %LocalApplicationData% but still not creating `OPCFoundation` folder and i dont have /home/USER/.local/share structure in my Linux machine

Comment: @MdShahnewaz I am not very familiar with OPC ua on Linux, it might be possible that the folder structure only is created in windows. I ran into this problem ealier using an Azure module called OPC publisher. (this runs on OPC foundation). So you might need to manually create the folders. (but again, haven't tried). If you cannot figure this out by your self let me know, I will try on linux tomorrow.

Comment: @MdShahnewaz On Windows, most of the special folders will exist by default. This may not be the case on Linux. It is the application's responsibility to create the folder when it doesn't exist. This may require some changes to your code to use the overload with a SpecialFolderOption. **[SOURCE](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux#)** . So as stated before you might need to make the folders manually

Comment: In windows machine certificate file generated here `C:\ProgramData\OPC Foundation\pki` but in Linux machine certificate file not generated even i created `/usr/share/OPCFoundation/pki` path manually still certificate not generated

Comment: @MdShahnewaz `/home/USER/.local/share` is a different path than `/usr/share`

Comment: I used /home/USER/.local/share path and gave write access also but still getting error message `(Access to the path '/home/USER/local/share/OPCFoundation/pki/own' is denied.`

Comment: @MdShahnewaz That is a linux problem

Comment: @MdShahnewaz I made a work around in my answer if you can't get the permissions working (You just use the windows standards to make a map on a other location

Comment: I used same path as you mentioned in your code  this time i'm not getting any kind of error message but still folder path not created `/usr/share/OPCFoundation/pki/own`.

Comment: @VictorPieper, I also faced same issue. I did not get any file access denied error message but path is not created /usr/share/OPCFoundation/pki/own

Comment: @Prabs [click here for extra help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946892/c-sharp-opc-ua-server-application-has-not-been-created-pki-certificate-in-linu/75947695#75947695)

Comment: @VictorPieper, I tried to give this path %LocalApplicationData%/OPC Foundation/pki/own in linux machine path has not created. when i try to give this path %CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\pki\own in windows machine then path and certificate created. there is no error also in linux machine..when opc ua server application called CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate method certificate creation shall happen but in linux the path has not created

Comment: @Prabs how did you run it? as superuser or normal

Comment: @VictorPieper i ran at normal user and there is no error in linux

Comment: @Prabs try to run: `Console.WriteLine("My folder: " + Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));` this. It will give you the path where the folders are created.