# C# - OPC-UA server application has not been created PKI certificate in Linux machine

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, pki, opc-ua

When I run `OPC-UA server` C# application in windows machine then OPC-UA server has created a certificate path `C:\ProgramData\OPC Foundation\pki\own`  and generates some certificates inside this path, but when I installed OPC-UA server in `Linux` machine then certificate path has not been created by server application and I am not getting any kind of error like access to the path denied. I am using below lines for creating certificate path in configuration file. Please help us.

```
<ApplicationCertificate>
            <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
            <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\pki\own</StorePath>
            <SubjectName>CN=OPCUA Server, C=US, S=Arizona, O=OPC Foundation, DC=localhost</SubjectName>
</ApplicationCertificate>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all on **[linux](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/Docs/Certificates.md#net-core-applications-on-windows-linux-ios-etc)** it is recommended to use: `%LocalApplicationData%`

```
ENM: System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
WIN: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local
LIN: /home/USER/.local/share
OSX: /Users/USER/.local/share
```

If you run it as superuser `/root/.local/share` is the path.

If you run it as normal user `/home/victor/.local/share`

If you want to see the path of a special folder use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("My folder: " + Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
```

Superuser path:
[image: my folder]

Normaluser path: [image: normal user]

This might help you locate your folders.

Since I ran the program as superuser it is in the (USER)->`root/.local/share` *You can only access this folder when logged in as root*

[image: location]

Here is anotherone with normal user:

[image: normal user]

My Securityconfiguration (I made a client but I guess it is almost the same with server):

```
    SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
                {
                    ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%LocalApplicationData%/OPCFoundation/CertificateStores/MachineDefault", SubjectName = "Mything" },
                    TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%LocalApplicationData%/OPCFoundation/CertificateStores/UA Certificate Authorities" },
                    TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%LocalApplicationData%/OPCFoundation/CertificateStores/UA Applications" },
                    RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%LocalApplicationData%/OPCFoundation/CertificateStores/RejectedCertificates" },
                    AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                    AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true
                },
```

This code will create the certificate on runtime:

```
application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: when I am using Backslash in path `<StorePath>%LocalApplicationData%\OPCFoundation\pki\own</StorePath>` then application running fine but certificate path not created, but when I used forward slash in path `<StorePath>%LocalApplicationData%/OPCFoundation/pki/own</StorePath>` then getting error `(Access to the path '/OPCFoundation/pki/own' is denied.)`

Comment: @MdShahnewaz are you using superuser or normal user?

Comment: I am normal user

Comment: @MdShahnewaz what kinda of os are you using? ubuntu? and with desktopview?

Comment: I am using ubuntu through `WinSCP`

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 /home` you can try giving the folder and subfolders read,write access for all users.

Comment: I gave read, write access to all folder and subfolders still certificate creation is not happening for us.

Comment: @MdShahnewaz I don't know furthermore, just make sure all the settings are right.